# What is this moba mobile game I saw on TikTok?

Tags: game-identification, mobile

Hello so I installed the Chinese TikTok and I've been seeing this really interesting game they play. Does anyone know what it is? I will provide a video below:

[image]

[Source](https://v.douyin.com/i8re7ox8/)

Seems similar to mobile legends but way cooler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the auto-translated comments on the video, it appears to be the game [Honor of Kings](https://www.honorofkings.com/)

Comment: And frankly; if you're gonna play a LoL knockoff, just play League Of Legends: Wild Rift; its almost indistinguishable from this

Comment: The UI shown in the (cropped) preview video from that link seem to match the screenshot as well.